# insert a many to many record into database EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a situation where I would like to have a user and society relationship. A user can be a member of many societies and in turn a society can have many members. I have these models...

```
public class Society {
  public int id { get; set; }
  public String societyName { get; set; }
  public String ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
  public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
  public DateTime dateLastUpdated { get; set; }
  public String location { get; set; }

  public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
  public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Members { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public ICollection<Society> Societies { get; set; }

}
```

So my understanding is that having an ICollection of corresponding types should create a table e.g. SocietyApplicationUser to join Users to Societies.

However I'm not seeing this table be created when I run my database migrations. 
Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Or should I just use fluentapi in my migrations configurations file?

As ever, thanks in advance.